# SQL VIEW only returning first record

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I'm not sure what is going on here.  I have created a MySQL view and to grab some data out of 4 different tables but it only seems to be returning the first record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW request_view AS
  SELECT
    TRequest.id,
    TRequest.minutes_required,
    TRequest.expires_at,
    User.name AS author,
    TRequest.abstract_text,
    TRequest.full_text,
    TGroup.name AS tgroup,
    SUM(TOrder.minutes) AS total_minutes
  FROM
    TRequest

  JOIN User ON TRequest.author_id = User.id
  LEFT JOIN TGroup ON TRequest.group_id = TGroup.id
  LEFT JOIN TOrder ON TRequest.id = TOrder.request_id

  ORDER BY TRequest.created_at;
```

When I try to select against this view it will only return the first record:

```
mysql> select id from request_view;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from request_view where id=2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I have 30 TRequest rows... is there anyway I can get the view to return all of the TRequest records?  Or am I simply using the View incorrectly?

Comment: How many rows do you have that have a corresponding record also in TRequest, TGroup and TOrder? I'm betting one. Can you include the contents of all the tables in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a `SUM` without a `GROUP BY`. `SUM` is an aggregate function which only make sense over a group of rows. If you don't specify any columns to group by, the default is to take the sum over all the rows, which means you only get one result.

If you want one row for each column in `TRequest`, try adding `GROUP BY TRequest.id` to your view definition.

Comment: That was exactly it.  This was my first time using stackoverflow.com and this was amazing.  Thanks everyone for your answers!

Comment: No problem @Ben! Happy developing :)

Answer (score 0):

The default `join` is an `inner join`, so this line can actually filter out rows:

```
 JOIN User ON TRequest.author_id = User.id
```

What happens if you replace it with:

```
 LEFT JOIN User ON TRequest.author_id = User.id
```